# Find a series representation for $ e^{2x} $ in powers of x +1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is from Swokowski Calculus book.

Find a series representation for $ e^{2x} $ in powers of x + 1.

I'm able to achieve
$$e^{2x} = \sum_0^\infty \frac{2^n x^n}{n!}$$

But I have no idea how to achieve the answer
$$e^{2x} = \sum_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2} 2^n}{n!}(x+1)^n$$

Comment: I think that $x^n$ does not belong in the second expression?

Comment: Consider the power series of $e^{2(x+1)}$ and use $e^{2(x+1)} = e^{2x} \cdot e^{2}$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor You are right. It should be $2^n$. Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Taylor series is defined by
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{1}{2!}f"(a)(x-a)^2 + ...$$

A MacLaurin series is a special case of Taylor series where $a=0$. That is what you have in the first expression.

So evaluate the terms of the Taylor series using $a = -1$.

The $n$th derivative of $e^{2x}$, $f^{(n)}$, is $2^ne^{2x}$, so plugging in, $f^{(n)}(a) = 2^ne^{-2}$

Comment: I was able to do it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You know that $e^y=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{y^n}{n!}$. Let $y=2x+2$; then

$$e^{2x+2}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(2x+2)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{2^n(x+1)^n}{n!}\,.$$

Now just divide both sides by $e^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Taylor's theorem, but I like the hint by @mattos in the comments:  $e^{2x}=e^{-2}e^{2(x+1)}=e^{-2}\sum_{n\ge0}2^n(x+1)^n/n!$.